# Google custom search API - sorting / filter

Tags: google-search, google-search-api

Is there anyway to filter the results by page title tag or certain meta tags... 
I read the documentation... but it's a mess :-(
Is anybody have an idea??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can sort and filter on custom meta tags.

First, put the data you want to filter on into [meta tags](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/structured_data#metatags):
  `<meta name="color" value="blue">`

Next, test that Google can find the tags by testing your URL with the [Rich Snippet Tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets) Under the 'Structured data for filtering search results', you should see `more:pagemap:metatags-color:blue`.

Finally, query your custom search engine with the structured data string above. Putting `more:pagemap:metatags-color:blue` in the search box works, or use it with your query parameter (usually `q`) in the URL.

For numeric meta tags, you can sort with `sort=more:pagemap:metatags-sales_rank` (or whatever your attribute is).

To search on page title it should work to use Google's standard `intitle:` operator.

Comment: How can i filter instead of sort? &filter= will work?

Comment: @DiogoAlves you can sort by date using the `sort=d` filter. Please read https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/structured_data#using-page-dates

Comment: Regarding 'How can I filter instead of sort?', you simply add that metatag filter after the &q: For example, this will filter all results matching the word 'stock' down to those with a tickersymbol metatag of AAPL or MSFT:  

&q=stock more:pagemap:metatags-tickersymbol:AAPL,MSFT 

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/structured_search#filter_by_attribute.