# Google Custom Search Filtering

Tags: google-search, google-search-api, google-custom-search

I have been given a set of (approved) requirements and an already approved solution to implement Google Custom Search into an existing website.

This website has the following:

- Jobs

  - Category 1
  - Category 2
  - Category 3
- Normal pages

  - Category 1
  - Category 2
  - Category 3

The requirement of the search functionality is that people can use CheckBoxes to filter results. So if the below was true:

```
[x] Category 1
[ ] Category 2
[x] Category 3
```

Then no pages would be shown from Category 2. However, there is also:

```
[x] Show jobs only
```

How am I able to implement this via Google Custom Search? I've read about `PageMap`, using `<meta>` tags, etc.. however I cannot understand how I am to filter results based on these.. ?

I looked here: [Google custom search API - sorting / filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338785/google-custom-search-api-sorting-filter)

However it doesn't appear to answer my concerns. I'm still a bit lost in the documentation.

Is this sort of thing possible? Does anyone have any links to some more thorough examples?

I had a thought to try in-memory filtering.. however if Google just *happens* to throw back a 1 Job page in 10 results while the `[x] Show jobs only` checkbox is checked.. then the user will only get 1 result on the page.

I am leaning towards the XML-based result set using the Custom Search Engine.. however if that needs to change I'm open to suggestions.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: All of the content is managed by a custom CMS on this particular site.. so using an XML file is out of the question really. Ideally we would dump whatever information Google needs into the pages themselves. However, I want to filter the results of the XML response BEFORE I get the XML.. does that make sense?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have managed to figure this out ... Only by lots of trial and error.

To begin, an example `PageMap` element in the XML response:

```
<PageMap>
    <DataObject type="metatags">
        <Attribute name="creationdate" value="D:20100902144455+10'00'"/>
        <Attribute name="creator" value="Adobe InDesign CS5 (7.0)"/>
        <Attribute name="moddate" value="D:20100902144510+10'00'"/>
        <Attribute name="producer" value="Adobe PDF Library 9.9"/>
    </DataObject>
</PageMap>
```

Google's filtering will only match individual words separated by spaces, special characters, etc. So, if I wanted to search for a "creator" with "CS5" in it, I would use this query string:

```
?q=My+Search+Text+Here+more:pagemap:metatags-creator:CS5
                                    ^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^
                                      type    name
```

The above "type" and "name" refer to the `DataObject` and `Attribute` element **attribute names**. The last part is the word you want to filter by.

So now I should be able to dump the following to to a page in Category 1:

```
<PageMap>
    <DataObject type="metatags">
        <Attribute name="category" value="Category1"/>
    </DataObject>
</PageMap>
```

Or.. for a job:

```
<PageMap>
    <DataObject type="metatags">
        <Attribute name="IsJobPage" value="Yes"/>
    </DataObject>
</PageMap>
```

..and use a query such as this:

```
?q=My+Search+Text+Here+more:pagemap:metatags-category:Category1,Category3
?q=My+Search+Text+Here+more:pagemap:metatags-IsJobPage:Yes
```

The first example returns any pages with a meta tag name of "category" that contains the value "Category1" **OR** "Category3".

Hopefully this answer saves someone from tearing their hair out.. like I almost did.

Comment: could you please let me know how to edit the query string? We are using <gcse:search> and I am not sure how to include the meta-tags info in the query string.

Comment: You just saved me... Thank you!