# Google CSE - sorting / filter by meta tags

Tags: meta-tags, microdata, google-search-api, google-custom-search

I am working on a Google CSE video search. I am stuck with an issue right now and that issue is, I want to filter/sort results on duration or date basis. I mean to say I want to sort/filter results on meta tags basis.

For example: https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool#url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DlF-jPBnZ098

There is a YouTube video and I have checked it on Google Structured Data Testing Tool and I and found that the each YT video contains the following meta info like:

```
  <meta itemprop="genre" content="Sports">
  <meta itemprop="duration" content="PT9M35S">
  <meta itemprop="datePublished" content="2016-06-09">
```

So somehow someway I want to filter my query with these meta tags. I saw this answer on Stack Overflow [Google custom search API - sorting / filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338785/google-custom-search-api-sorting-filter) which looks very similar to my query but it's not working for me.

I tried these queries and I am getting no result.

```
q=my+query+more:pagemap:metatags-genre:sports
q=my+query+more:pagemap:metatags-duration:2
q=my+query+more:pagemap:metatags-datapublished:2016-01-09
```

I also tried it with sort parameter but no success at all

```
q=my+query&sort=more:pagemap:metatags
```

I am getting no result at all. Nothing is working, just getting frustated. I dont know what kind of mistake I am doing?

I learned these article on Google but I did not find much help:

- https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/structured_search?csw=1
- https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2012/05/sorting-and-filtering-results-in-custom.html
- https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/structured_data

So if someone know how to do it please help!

Comment: Note that this is Microdata (it defines `itemprop` and other attributes), while "meta tags" are typically only called `meta` elements with a `name` attribute (instead of `itemprop`).

Comment: I also notied that, its itemprop and for once i did    q=my+query+more:pagemap:itemprop-genre:sports but no sucess at all. i believe due to itemprop i am not getting expected results, any idea how to do it ? @unor

Comment: Sorry, no, I have no experience with Google CSE. Just thought you might find a solution if you search for "Microdata" (and/or "Schema.org", which is often used within Microdata).